# Docker save is not saving the lastest version of the images files

Tags: docker

Im having some trouble saving and loading a docker image from my host laptop to a demo server on google cloud platform

Im running

```
docker save services > services.tar
```

then uploading the tar to GCP and  running

```
docker load < services.tar
```

and running the instance

The problem I have is that when I attach to the new instance to run some processes Im getting old versions of the files. It looks like they are the files that I had from the first time I created the docker image on my host laptop. Also none of the applications that I installed like vim are getting saved and loaded.

Is there a way to ensure that when Im saving the image that it exports all of the files and installed applications as they are at the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save docker images with compress option and very less size by executing below command

```
docker save image:latest |gzip >image.tar.gz
```

Comment: It was a combination of this and the having to mount a shared files space and copy across the files that I needed. Thanks